# I can't get the image apply correctly

Tags: image

[image]I can't get the image to apply correctly. I tried UV unwrapping it but I can't get it to work properly. It works fine on a square shaped objects but whenever I try to apply it on an unusual shape objects. The image is distorted.

Comment: I think we'll need to see your Blend file preferably with just the object which is causing problems in it. You'll also need to pack any image(s) used into the Blend file which you can do via File > External Data > Pack Resources before sharing the blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ if it's under 30Meg in size following the instructions there to copy the link on that page and then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Comment: Have you tried different projection methods?  I.e. cube project?

Comment: Yes i have. And it still doesn't work. I have tried to upload more pictures.To give you a better idea what is going on but for some reason it only letting me upload one picture.

Comment: please pack your images (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file

Comment: Ok, I've found a solution to your problem. Read my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATED]

I've examined the newly added file – and I've found the source of your problem.

The objects in your file are made using Boolean Operations.

Booleans have many side effects and you've experienced one of them:

after objects have been interacted via booleans – the result object inherits BOTH uv-maps.

Non of which does work correctly with the new geometry. That's the reason for many glitches, including the one you've experienced in this case :

[image]

---

To solve this issue you need to delete the old maps [–] and create a new one [+].

After that you can unwrap the object:  either automatically (using Smart UV Project) or manually (which is a better option)

I've made the manual unwrapping for you. Now your objects look this way :

[image]

---

You can adjust how the texture applied by moving, rotating and scaling geometry in the uv-editor – it's on the left side of the screenshot here :

[image]

---

(1) Here is the fixed file: [image]

---

(2) And  - since I've completely rewrote my answer - the link to the video about the manual unwrapping I've mentioned before: [=VIDEO (link)=](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jnzhNdWoXMg)

---

---

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will take a look at the video.

Comment: I uploaded the file.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=M4JmSxzo" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/M4JmSxzo/)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: @Brian Mason if the answer is correct please mark it as such   ;)